# converting to datetime using Convert.ToDateTime

Tags: c#, .net

I have a "string" in format mm/dd/yyyy and want to change this to "Feb 2, 2011".

Can this be done using Convert.ToDateTime?

Thanks
Behrouz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert your string to DateTime First and then Convert to string using required format

```
 String.Format("{0:MMM d, yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(date));
```

Here is [link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Comment: Thank you exactly what I was looking. I tried it and it works.

Answer (score 3):

```
 DateTime dateObject= DateTime.Parse(yourDateString);
 dateObject.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

or in single line

```
string result = DateTime.Parse(yourDateString).ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
var dateString = "02/02/2011";
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(dateString).ToString("MMM d, yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert.ToDateTime(string date,IFormatProvider provider) where the format provider should be "{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}".

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
string test = "1/21/2011";

string result = Convert.ToDateTime(test).ToLongDateString();

MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Regards!